# How can I moderate user's edits of user profile?

Tags: 7, users

I need to create approval for editing a user's profile - I want all revisions to a profile to be subject to moderation.

I have found module called [User Revision](https://drupal.org/project/user_revision), but that is not a solution for me as it's only revisioning.

Is this possible with [Workbench](https://drupal.org/project/workbench) or something similar?

I am not using [Profile 2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2); and I am working on the newest Drupal 7 version (7.23 at time of writing).

Comment: Can't this be simply resolved with a user role and relevant permissions?

Comment: Hello Chapabu, no this is not possible at all

Comment: So you are looking for something like [revision moderation](https://drupal.org/project/revision_moderation), only it [wasn't ported to d7](https://drupal.org/node/995876) and thus can't work for you? But if it would work for any entity revisions, it would be what you need?

Comment: Hello Molot
yes, this is what i am searching.
Do you know about something?
thank you

Comment: @edryen Last time I needed something remotely like this was in Drupal 6 and I basically hacked it from a bits of Revision Moderation and Advertisement modules and own code. I just wanted to make sure I know what you want, as someone already voted to put your question on hold as unclear. Also, use `@` before my name if you want me to get notified.

Comment: are you using any content type as profile?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 0):

There is drupal module [Profile2 Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_moderation) to achieve this. It enables moderation on user profiles.

> A "quite hackish procedure"™ to enable moderation on user profiles but it works